# Spring Webapp in Weblogic publish error

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, weblogic

I am getting the below exception, when I try to publish my Spring MVC Webapp:

> Context initialization failed || java.lang.LinkageError: loader
>   constraint violation: loader (instance of
>   org/springframework/context/support/ContextTypeMatchClassLoader$ContextOverridingClassLoader)
>   previously initiated loading for a different type with name
>   "org/apache/http/params/HttpParams"   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.ContextTypeMatchClassLoader$ContextOverridingClassLoader.loadClassForOverriding(ContextTypeMatchClassLoader.java:109)
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.OverridingClassLoader.loadClass(OverridingClassLoader.java:61)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:467)
>     at
>   org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:481)
>     at
>   org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:451)
>     at
>   org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:511)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:634)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isTypeMatch(AbstractBeanFactory.java:510)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:339)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:308)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:638)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:454)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:481)
>     at
>   weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
>     at
>   weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:181)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1873)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3161)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1511)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:483)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:200)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:247)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:27)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:636)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:205)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:58)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161)
>     at
>   weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
>     at
>   weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activate(BasicDeployment.java:184)
>     at
>   weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activateFromServerLifecycle(BasicDeployment.java:361)
>     at
>   weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter$1.doActivate(DeploymentAdapter.java:51)
>     at
>   weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter.activate(DeploymentAdapter.java:200)
>     at
>   weblogic.management.deploy.internal.AppTransition$2.transitionApp(AppTransition.java:30)
>     at
>   weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionApps(ConfiguredDeployments.java:240)
>     at
>   weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.activate(ConfiguredDeployments.java:169)
>     at
>   weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.deploy(ConfiguredDeployments.java:123)
>     at
>   weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.resume(DeploymentServerService.java:180)
>     at
>   weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.start(DeploymentServerService.java:96)
>     at weblogic.t3.srvr.SubsystemRequest.run(SubsystemRequest.java:64)
>     at
>   weblogic.work.ExecuteRequestAdapter.execute(ExecuteRequestAdapter.java:21)
>     at weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:145)    at
>   weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:117)^^

Answer (score 1):

You're VERY likely loading the same class twice and with two different versions. Specifically you might have two versions of:

```
org/apache/http/params/HttpParams
```

Check the application you are loading and what weblogic already supplies. You can either remove the duplicate class/jar like:

[java.lang.LinkageError Error in Class Loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841769/java-lang-linkageerror-error-in-class-loading)

[java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/xml/soap/SOAPMessage"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17152274/java-lang-linkageerror-loader-constraint-violation-previously-initiated-loading)

Or you can use preferred classes in weblogic to explicitly state which version of the class to use (likely the one packaged in your application). See:

[NetBeans taking JSF Server library instead of registered libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19816632/netbeans-taking-jsf-server-library-instead-of-registered-libraries/19818913#19818913)